# Creating a timer that tells me how much time has passed since the last time it passed through a function

Tags: python, timeit

I'm basically trying to know the time difference between the time since the previous time it passed through the function.  Unfortunately the project is rather big and the structure consists of many functions and modules that are all more or less interconnected so I don't think the timeit module is adequate or am i wrong?

Comment: Might not be exactly what you want, but I'd suggest adding distributed tracing to the code instead of littering it with timer code

Comment: That's bit like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut, since time between two code executions is really the only thing I need.

Comment: Maybe, but how do you guarantee this function will ever be called again? Calculating time between calls can only be calculated based on times it was called

Comment: I guess I'd have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do as followed: create a decorator, store in a `/tmp/` file the last timestamp the function was called. And every time the function is called, go check the value in that file and compare it to the current timestamp.

Since the name of the file you store to depends on the function name, you can monitor several functions at the same time without any interference.

```py
import time
import os


def mytimeit(func):
    timerfile = os.path.join("/tmp", func.__name__)

    def timed(*args, **kwargs):
        # Read content of storing file
        # The file name in our case is /tmp/foo
        lasttime = None
        try:
            with open(timerfile, "r") as f:
                lasttime = "\n".join([f.readlines()[0]]).strip()
                lasttime = float(lasttime)
        except Exception as e:
            # The file does not exist: the function has never been called
            print("First time calling foo")
            pass
    
        now = time.time()
        if lasttime is not None:
            print("Last time {} was called was {} seconds ago".format(func.__name__, now - lasttime))

        # Let's save the new timestamp that will be used to know
        # when is the last time the function was called
        with open(timerfile, "w") as f:
            f.write(str(now))

        # Call the decorated function (in our case, "foo")
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        return result
    
    return timed


@mytimeit
def foo():
    print("Calling foo")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo()
    time.sleep(2)
    foo()
    time.sleep(5)
    foo()
    time.sleep(1)
    foo()
```

It gives the following result:

```
First time calling foo
Calling foo
Last time foo was called was 2.002573013305664 seconds ago
Calling foo
Last time foo was called was 5.007807493209839 seconds ago
Calling foo
Last time foo was called was 1.0037212371826172 seconds ago
Calling foo
```